# Modrewrite transparent rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have a domain/subdomain pointing to a folder called htdocs.

When the exampledomain.com is accessed I want it to get the files in `/htdocs/dev/`

Currently it gets the files in `/htdocs/` and if the files that are in /dev/ they need to be
accessed with `exampledomain.com/dev/`

How can I do this? I don't want to use a redirect. I don't want this to reflect in the address bar. I also don't want to change any server specifics as we're on a shared platform. What can be done with .htaccess?

Thanks for your help! It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and easiest way is just to change your pointer to point the domain to the /htdocs/dev/ folder.  Shared hosting isn't an issue for you even if you're sharing hosting with a friend.  Their root folder holds all the sub folders for the individual websites.  Pointing your domain name to /htdocs/dev/ takes care of all your issues unless I'm reading the question wrong.. =)

Answer (score 1):

@davidisinaband's solution is the simplest one: set /htdocs/dev as the document root, instead of /htdocs.  But if for some reason you can't or don't want to do that, then the following rewrite rule should do what you want:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev(/|$)
RewriteRule (.*) /dev$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that shows the redirected url in the address bar. Is there a way to get around that?